# Too many Redirects after switching WordPress to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

with my WordPress-Blog, I switch to https. Therefore, I have add the following code to my .htaccess-File. My Problem now is, that I get the issue "Too many Redirects". Thank you for your tips!

Domain is a Subdomain:

https://en.example.com

```
# Begin Force SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# End Force SSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your first three lines to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I *believe*, that unless you attempted to go to https://en.example.com/:443 then {SERVER_PORT} will never return 443.

Comment: Is there a publicly-accessible URL to view your site's behavior?

Comment: Oh there is still a problem: Currently I´m also able to open the URL with http only.

Comment: So, it isn't forwarding you to https?

Comment: sorry for the late response. Now it works! I think, it was a server cache issue.

Comment: What if I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error? How do I fix that?

Comment: This would indicate that you most likely have another conflicting rule.

Comment: Hi, I used that code but getting 500 internal server error, any idea why?

Answer (score 83):

Make sure that you define the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME at wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```

And add this condition to check if the https at wp-config.php

```
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    }
```

Comment: this method when use external ssl tunnel like cloadflare

Comment: After two days of crying I finally fixed it.
Yes, I'm using external SSL tunnel - CloudFlare + VPS

Comment: Perfect, solved to me using a nginx reverse proxy with HTTPS.

Comment: great its working .its cause by cloudflare

Comment: That bit about setting `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` did the trick when running on Kubernetes and Nginx Ingress

Answer (score 70):

I have soved the issue using the below code inside wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://mywebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://mywebsite.com');
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Comment: With Cloudflare `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` was enough for me.

Comment: This, in combination with adding the rewrite rules in .htaccess worked for me too! Thanks!

Comment: This saved my life. I spent full week to fix `TOO MANY REDIRECTS` error but did not get success. But these small but important lines saved me.

Comment: It woked for me too. Had spent hours trying to figure this out but finally theses three lines solved my problem. Thank you so much for posting this.

Comment: With AWS ELB terminating SSL $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; was enough for me

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` works for me too. The best solution for cloud flare users.

Comment: jazaakallahu khairan, 3rd line solve my problem

Answer (score 19):

I had same problem nginx and had to do following
in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in `wp-config.php`

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('RELOCATE', TRUE);
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
define('WP_HOME', 'https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://yourdomain.com');
```

don't use the below with nginx unless you make sure it passes HTTPS is on to fast cgi, otherwise it won't work,

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

it might be of benefit log debug level in error log of nginx, this is how you get to see the flow.

Comment: Just saved our day! Is there any problem using RELOCATE?

Comment: Thanks. Only this line `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` solves the problem for me

Comment: That saves me. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: this one definitely fixed it

Comment: Thanks this fixed. I think WP_HOME shouldn't have www and ending '/'

Comment: Helped me! This is answer in most cases

Comment: Afer adding this, how page started to wor but pages are going to Not Found

Comment: work for me after 2 days search

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you define the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` at `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```

And add this condition to check if the https at wp-config.php

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

This works well

Comment: Nice, this way i can solve the problem without changes in .htaccess, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**if use Cloudflare and Nginx:**

1- go to the cloud flare and add always use HTTPS in page rules.

2- add the below code into the wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/blog');

if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

**Note: don't change anything in the database and using incognito mode.**

Comment: Nice, this way i can solve the problem without changes in .htaccess, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt: Adding the following lines of code at the start of **wp-config.php** file resolved the redirect conflict.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly the answer, but something else to note is that some browsers will cache redirects, so you might be changing your htaccess or wp-config without seeing any changes.

Best way to debug this is using incognito mode.

The above answers worked for me, but it took ages to work out that they had actually worked because of the browser redirect caching!