# After changing wordpress to https Google results still redirect to http

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have followed several answers to redirect a wordpress site to https.

I didn't do it through an .htaccess, since it caused a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29478955/1883256) didn't work.

The only way I've made this work so far is just by changing the two URLs of my domain from the wordpress control panel.

What I have noticed is that, from Google results in one example, the link does not redirect to the https article, but still to http and nothing is shown.

For example, in Google, type: `sivacore patrotsky`, the second result takes to the following link http://blog.patrotsky.com/?portfolio=importacion-de-datos and no content is shown. It does not redirect to this https link: https://blog.patrotsky.com/?portfolio=importacion-de-datos where my content is shown.

How do I fix this?

However, if you only type in your browser's url bar: `blog.patrotsky.com`, it does redirect to `https://blog.patrotsky.com` as expected.

Comment: did you wait for google to re-spider your side and notice that you redirected to https?

Comment: It's been at least one week since I made those changes ...

Comment: that doesn't mean much. if google only visits your site once a month... check the access logs for googlebot hits, and make sure you see your site responding with a 301, not a 200

Comment: Then how can I make the content available for http and https meanwhile? Or how to make a proper redirect for every article to https??

Comment: fix your redirect to so that any http url gets redirect to the equivalent https. then it doesn't matter what url google is serving up in its results - the viewer will end up on the https one anyways.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks!! I got it and solved it ;)