# Getting mixed content warning - WordPress behind nginx-proxy with letsencrypt ssl

Tags: wordpress, nginx, lets-encrypt, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have a WordPress site running in Docker behind nginx with HTTPS (Letsencrypt), but I am having trouble with some essential scripts that won't load because the browser claims they are unauthenticated. I also see the dreaded 'Skip to content' link on the homepage. I set things up with jwilder/nginx-proxy and the letsencrypt companion. All my site data is loaded from a MySQL dump, and my initial assumption was that I had to change all the `http://example.org` entries in the dump file to `https://example.org`. However I was getting a 301 redirect with that ('too many redirects' error in the browser), so I changed all the links back to http. Now the site loads, but with the unathenticated error (if I accept the unauthenticated links the site loads, of course).

I have seen [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49096266/795131) [solutions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/279984) to this, or what I think might be solutions, which all seem to involve adding entries to .htaccess and/or wp-config.php. Indeed adding the following to my wp-config.php seems to solve the 'Skip to content' issue:

```
/** SSL */  
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);  
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain  
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https  
// so check for https existence  
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)  
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

However some pages are still complaining about unauthenticated content, and that the site is not fully secure... Not sure what else to do. Do I need to modify .htaccess too?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was caused by urls for images and vtt files that had links added in the WordPress admin with http. Updating for https seems to have fixed it.